# How to call stored procedure procedure from spring data JPA where procedure is

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

How to call stored procedure procedure from spring data JPA where procedure is equal to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ERPDEV.INTG_TO_TRAN_PROC AS IN_USER_ID NUMBER;
  IN_USER_DEVICE_ID                                                NUMBER;
  IN_IN_DATE                                                       DATE;
  IN_IN_TIME                                                       DATE;
  IN_OUT_TIME                                                      DATE;
  IN_DIFF_TIME                                                     NUMBER;
  IN_USER_DEVICE_LOCATION                                          VARCHAR2(25);
  IN_FLOOR_TIME                                                    NUMBER;
  BEGIN FOR REC1 IN (SELECT
                       C.USER_ID,
                       C.USER_DEVICE_ID
                     FROM USER_DEVICE_MAP C) LOOP IN_USER_ID := REC1.USER_ID;
    IN_USER_DEVICE_ID := REC1.USER_DEVICE_ID;
    IN_FLOOR_TIME := 0;
    FOR REC IN (SELECT
                  B.DEVICE_ID,
                  B.USER_DEVICE_ID,
                  B.USER_DEVICE_LOCATION,
                  B.IN_DATE,
                  B.IN_TIME,
                  B.OUT_TIME
                FROM BIOMETRIC_INTEGRATION B
                WHERE B.USER_DEVICE_ID = IN_USER_DEVICE_ID AND B.IN_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE)
                ORDER BY B.DEVICE_ID) LOOP IN_USER_DEVICE_LOCATION := REC.USER_DEVICE_LOCATION;
      IN_IN_TIME := REC.IN_TIME;
      IN_OUT_TIME := REC.OUT_TIME;
      IN_IN_DATE := REC.IN_DATE;
      IN_DIFF_TIME := 0;
      IN_DIFF_TIME := (IN_OUT_TIME - IN_IN_TIME) * 24;
      IN_FLOOR_TIME := IN_FLOOR_TIME + IN_DIFF_TIME;
    END LOOP;
    INSERT INTO BIOMETRIC_TRANSACTION (TRAN_ID, USER_ID, USER_DEVICE_ID, USER_DEVICE_LOCATION, IN_DATE, FIRST_IN_TIME, LAST_OUT_TIME, TOTAL_TIME_ON_FLOOR)
    VALUES
      (BIO_TRAN_SEQ.NEXTVAL, IN_USER_ID, IN_USER_DEVICE_ID, IN_USER_DEVICE_LOCATION, IN_IN_DATE, (SELECT MIN(IN_TIME)
                                                                                                  FROM
                                                                                                    BIOMETRIC_INTEGRATION
                                                                                                  WHERE USER_DEVICE_ID =
                                                                                                        IN_USER_DEVICE_ID),
       (SELECT MAX(OUT_TIME)
        FROM BIOMETRIC_INTEGRATION
        WHERE USER_DEVICE_ID = IN_USER_DEVICE_ID), ROUND(IN_FLOOR_TIME, 2));
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below :

### Entity Class

```
@Entity

@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "User.plus1", procedureName = "plus1inout", parameters = {

  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "arg", type = Integer.class),

  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "res", type = Integer.class) 

})

public class User {}
```

### Repository method should be like

```
@Procedure("plus1inout")
Integer explicitlyNamedPlus1inout(Integer arg);
```